# Piping multiple audio files to totem media player

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, totem

My gf likes the Beatles so I placed a couple of tracks on my harddisk ...

```
Beatles - Here Comes The Sun.mp3
Beatles - If I Fell.mp3
Beatles - Tell me why.mp3
Beatles - Things we said today.mp3
```

... now from terminal - I can easily enqueue a track to my media player totem

```
totem --enqueue "Beatles - Here Comes The Sun.mp3"
```

But sometimes my gf likes to give me smoochies, thus, keeping me busy from spending all day enqueueing tracks one by one.

**Is there a way to enque multiple tracks with a single command?**

... it doesn't have to be simple ... but she thinks single command lines are so hot, resulting in more smoochies :)  Also, please presume that the files could be scattered in subdirectories.

I've tried the following but it didn't work ...

```
totem --enqueue "$(find -iname "*beatles*")"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the spacing in the filenames that it doesn't work...

Try

```
find -iname '*beatles*' -exec totem --enqueue {} +
```

this executes `totem --enqueue` with all files found, but escapes the spaces properly.

Comment: Thank you, that worked just perfectly.  This will result in a lot of smoochies! :)

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work with `totem --replace` to start a new playlist ... but that would be a new question alltogether.

Comment: I was wrong, will update answer soon...

Comment: There! the answer is much better and faster now, it all had to do with escaping the spaces of the files. As a bonus, it also works with `--replace` now :D

Comment: Oh, yes!  Perfect, once again.  And as you said, faster, too :)